# ByteArrayOutputStream - get bytes from string

Tags: java

How can I get similar result

```
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream("asd".bytes())
```

this code don't compile

Comment: What exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: Are you missing the `;` at the end?

Comment: What's the compile error?

Comment: `String` doesn't have a `bytes` method... So no, it can't compile...

Comment: How about [getBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes())

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write this : `OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();outputStream.write("asd".getBytes());`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle is correct. I'm afraid I have to vote to close as a typo here.

Answer (score 1):

Class ByteArrayOutputStream have two constructors

```
ByteArrayOutputStream() by default value  
and with parameter ByteArrayOutputStream(int size)
```

instead "asd".bytes() you must write "asd".length();